# SVG Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, svg, memory-leaks, domparser

A add [small example (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/3y3k0/N8nDj/9/), where I recreate SVG with 900 inner element in requestAnimationFrame loop.

```
function SVGBuilder(){
    this._parser = new DOMParser();
    this._svg = null;
}
SVGBuilder.prototype.build = function(){
    var string = 
        '<svg width="300px" height="300px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + 
        Array.apply(null, {length:900}).map(function(_, i){
            return '<rect class="rect" x="'+(i*10%300)+'" y="'+(i/30|0)*10+'" width="10" height="10" fill="#'+(Math.random()*1000000).toString(16).slice(-6)+'"/>'
        }).join('') +
        '</svg>'
    if (this._svg) this._svg.parentNode.removeChild(this._svg);
    this._svg = this.parse(string).documentElement;
    document.body.appendChild(this._svg);
}

SVGBuilder.prototype.parse = function(string) {
    return this._parser.parseFromString(string, 'image/svg+xml');
}

var SVG = new SVGBuilder();
function draw(){
    SVG.build();
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

I know that it's bad realisation of repainting, but I don't see the place where I can get high memory leak. What I miss?

Comment: I wouldn't know what's causing it, but chrome went up to 2,5gig of memory usage for that tab, so at least I can confirm a massive memory leak.
Would it be an option to use a `<canvas>` instead of svg?

Comment: I can rewrite it without memory leaks using canvas or other algorithm for svg, but I need explanation why this leaking.

Comment: you have an impicit tail recursion in your function draw that never rewinds.

Comment: Correct me but I think it's not recursion. ```requestAnimationFrame``` is async function